# iOS Lag While Loading PDFs

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, pdf-generation, cgcontext

So My Application uses, a lot of PDF's These sheet take a long time to load, (10 seconds + on iPad 2, iOS 7) So i figured if I could get the Load the separate sheets into the File directory, at ApplicationDidFinishLaunching() - I could then refers to the files in the user directory and they would load faster - but it made absolutely no difference

Below is my DrawRect() method responsible for displaying the PDF

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
//PDF might be transparent, assume white paper - set White Background
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
CGContextFillRect(ctx, rect);

//PDF File Path
//"pdf" refers to the location in the directory where the file is saved"
CGPDFPageRef page1 = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1);

//Flip coordinates
CGContextGetCTM(ctx);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -rect.size.height);

//Get the rectangle of the cropped inside
CGRect mediaRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page1, kCGPDFCropBox);

CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, rect.size.width / mediaRect.size.width,
                  rect.size.height / mediaRect.size.height);

//Draw PDF
CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page1);
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
```

Location in the directory where the file is as was declared in the idInit() method

```
NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dataPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PDFSource"]];
    NSString *documentDirectoryFilename = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                           [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BUEvenous.pdf"]];

    CFStringRef path = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, [documentDirectoryFilename UTF8String], kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, path, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);
    CFRelease (path);
    pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url);// 2
    CFRelease(url);
```

Your help guidance, suggestions, any points as to where I'm going wrong of how I could make this load faster is very much appreciated

**EDIT**

@DavidvanDriessche thank you for the suggestion, it turnes out that the PDF files I am using are actually quite large (about 1 MB), what I learnt from testing is that if i further compress the PDF files so they're =< 500kbs then i don't have an issue with loading time - but compressing the files, lead to loss of image quality on some of the embedded images within the PDF : also it could be the iPad 2 - I'll try running it on a newer device and add to this post

Any other suggestions ?

Task

Comment: Does this happen with any PDF file or is it something you only see with your particular files? There are some features of PDF that are much more expensive than others; examples are complex pages with lots of vector elements and clipping going on and JPEG-2000 encoded images to just name a few. On top of that many of the older devices (such as the iPad 2) have very limited memory and a quite slow processor to deal with heavy files. But find out whether it's PDF specific first - just try with very simple PDF files to see what the difference is.

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche I figured I'd add your answer as an edit to the question as it may be helpful for someone else stabling upon a similar issue - Thank you for your input

Answer (score 2):

You could consider creating images from pdf pages instead, and do so in a background thread, via `NSOperation` or using  `dispatch_async`

To create an image from a pdf page:

```
+(UIImage *)getPDFPage:(CGPDFPageRef) page rect:(CGRect) rect
{

    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, pageRect.size.height);

    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);

    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

**EDIT:**

This code will give you an image in a size decided by the PDF file (the `pageRect` in code above). Zoom level will therefore be decided by the media available. Take a look at the different values for `CGPDFPageGetBoxRect` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPDFPage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGPDFBox).

Keep in mind that the images might take up a lot of memory. You could save the images to disk using:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pdfImage);
```

And then load the relevant page when needed. Loading an image from the iUnit disk is pretty fast.

Comment: thank you Esben, I could do this: but than my application would lose the lossless zoom which is a major advantage when working with PDF Files -right ?

Comment: @TaskinulHaque I have just updatede my answer with some additional info. Good luck and Happy coding!